# UI design - Include a Cancel button or not?

Tags: user-interface

We are designing the UI for a new line of business application. We have no real constraints and are free to design the UI as we see fit. The UI will be done in WPF and targeted for Windows 7, Vista, and XP Pro users.

Many dialog boxes contain OK and Cancel buttons in their lower right corner. Do you feel it is necessary to have this Cancel button or is the red X in the upper right corner sufficient? We are discussing this as we have been noticing more UIs that do not have cancel buttons, only the red X.

Answer (score 20):

Not only you should add it but also make sure ESC is mapped to it.

Answer (score 7):

Present the two designs to the customer - one with the "Cancel" button, the other without. See what their thoughts are.

Better still present them as partially working prototypes and watch them as they use the dialogs. If you ask them to perform a set of tasks and see if they have trouble when asked to cancel an operation.

Having said that, my preference is to include a "Cancel" button for the reasons others have mentioned:

- Accessibility (especially as Esc should be mapped to it).
- Convention (users will be expecting it).

Comment: It would be nice if people explained their down votes - oh well

Comment: Why the downvote here? Usability _is_ about finding out whether users are getting confused or not, after all. Asking them might not be the best way, watching them will be better. But still, getting stakeholders involved is a lot better than just making random guesses. +1 for an almost-good idea and to even out the downvote.

Answer (score 6):

Include the Cancel button. The red X is VERY hard to tab to. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Include it.  This is very common in other user interfaces.  Give the user the choice of which to use; making it for them might make them annoyed with your interface.

Answer (score 1):

Users are used to having standard GUI layouts - otherwise they get confused. They also  have different ways of using the standard interface. Some people only use the *X*, some people only use *Cancel*. People usually ignore the one they're not using, but get confused if their one isn't present. So be safe and keep them both in - it should only be a one-liner function for Cancek anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Include it!

Answer (score 1):

From a user interface perspective, not including a cancel button might leave some users feeling like they have no choice, which is certainly not the case. Imagine the following simple decision scenario:

> Warning: All of the files in the selected folder will be deleted. This action cannot be undone. Are you sure you would like to continue?

How silly would an interface be if the only option was Ok? Also, as noted above, on many platforms the Escape key is mapped to Cancel. It's also probably worthwhile setting a default button so that pressing the Enter/Space key doesn't inadvertently perform the action that cannot be undone.

Answer (score 0):

+1 on including it. If you don't include it now and then need some different functionality on Cancel to Close later on, your users will already be used to automatically closing.

Answer (score 0):

Just like we have 'ESC' button on keyboard, we need 'Cancel' in dialogs.

A matter of usability :-)

Answer (score 0):

Include it.  And **please** also make sure that you make sure that hitting the Escape key does the same thing as the Cancel button.

Also, just because you're designing from scratch, please don't throw out all convention.  Take a look at MSFT's [UX Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511268.aspx) for dialog boxes.

Answer (score 0):

The red button is really for 'Close' rather than 'Cancel'. 'Cancel' canceling a running task. Use a 'Close' button instead. And yes include the 'Close' if there is a reason for people to click on it. The red button is quite difficult to click when you really want to close something quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have that kind of freedom, consider eliminating dialog boxes from your application entirely, especially ones with the typical "OK | CANCEL" paradigm. Dialog boxes disrupt the flow of action and generally should only be used for things which absolutely require the program to interrupt the user.

You'll notice how disruptive they are in the web environment -- e.g., Stack Overflow only uses them when it needs to be able to OVERRIDE your action, e.g., when you navigate away from an unsubmitted answer.