# jQuery-mobile sliding menu under header

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I just entered into jQuery mobile, and saw the next [example](http://www.objectpartners.com/2013/05/13/adding-a-sliding-menu-to-your-jquery-mobile-app/)

Is it possible to make the sliding menu appear under the header? (in the red lines in the image)

[image]

Comment: some code please? Maybe a fiddle? :)

Comment: Here is a link to my original blog post that has the fiddle and tutorial: http://www.objectpartners.com/2013/05/13/adding-a-sliding-menu-to-your-jquery-mobile-app/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Override `.ui-panel` style by changing `top` position and `min-height` values

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2dN4M/)**

Calculate header's `.outerHeight()` and panel's `.height()`.

```
var header = $('[data-role=header]').outerHeight(); 
var panel = $('.ui-panel').height();
```

Give panel a new `min-height` in order not to cause page to scroll

```
var panelheight = panel - header;
```

Override panel style

```
$('.ui-panel').css({
    'top': header,
    'min-height': panelheight
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done even better:

This works for the following situation:

- Panel: `data-display="push"`
- Panel: `data-position="left"`
- Header: `data-position="fixed"`

and change the following css styles:

```
.ui-panel {
    top: 41px;
    height: calc(100% - 41px);
}

.ui-panel-animate.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-position-left.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-open.ui-panel-content-fixed-toolbar-display-push {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

The first is to move the panel a bit down so it moves under the header while the second makes the header stay still instead of also moving to the side.

I guess that for different `Panel` and `Header` settings a different combination of CSS classes is used. You'll need to fiddle with that.

demo: http://jsbin.com/avuviy/2/

Answer (score 1):

Along with the excellent answer by Omar, you could consider these options also as a solution.

- You make use the first element in the `listview` as a button to close your panel. (Yes, users love it when you add a close button, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007765/ui-design-include-a-cancel-button-or-not)). Just add an anchor tag inside in the first `li` element and you're set.

  ```
  <li data-icon="false"><a href="#my-header" data-rel="close" data-icon="delete"></a></li>
  ```
- You could leave that place to be empty. (yeah i know, sounds kinda lame, but it wont hinder your design - its **un-obstrusive**. Just add an empty `h1` tag to the first li:

  ```
  <li data-icon="false"><h1></h1></li>
  ```

Here's a demo : http://jsbin.com/avuviy/1/edit

Comment: Hey @Omar i am using above code its working fine.. but i want to know how to make. this pannel scrollable . my content in panel exceding beyond screen i want to make it scorllable .. please tell me how to fix

Comment: @rachar_P Hi, please post a question and add details in order to be able to assist you :)