# Jquery-mobile sliding menu panel +scrolling

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am new to jQuery Mobile. I need to add a Facebook sliding panel features to my application.

I gone through with [sliding menu panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027951/jquery-mobile-sliding-menu-under-header), it's working fine, but my content in menu panel is exceeding the window size and I want to make it scrollable.

Please tell me how to fix it.

code Refer as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>FB Style Menu</title>
<meta id="extViewportMeta" name="viewport"content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .ui-panel-inner {
    overflow: hidden !important;
    padding: 0px;
}
.ui-controlgroup {
    margin: 0;
}
#header {
    height: 54px;
}
#bars-button {
    margin: 7px;
}
.panel-content {
    overflow-y: scroll !important
}
</style>

<script>
    $(document).on('pageshow', '#home', function(event) {
        alert("init");
    init(); //$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();    
    });    
    function init() {    
        var header = $('[data-role=header]').outerHeight();
        var panel = $('.ui-panel').height();
        var panelheight = panel - header;
        $('.ui-panel').css({
            'top' : header,
            'min-height' : panelheight
        });    
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="panel" id="navpanel" data-theme="a" data-display="overlay" data-position="right">
        <div class="panel-content">
            <div data-role="controlgroup" data-corners="false"> <a href="#" data-role="button">Business</a>
                <a href="#" data-role="button">Numbers</a>
                <a href="#" data-role="button">Money</a>
                <a href="#" data-role="button">People</a>
                <a href="#" data-role="button">Business</a>
                <a href="#" data-role="button">Numbers</a>
                <a href="#" data-role="button">Money</a>
                <a href="#" data-role="button">People</a>
                <a href="#" data-role="button">Business</a>
                <a href="#" data-role="button">Numbers</a>
                <a href="#" data-role="button">Money</a>
                <a href="#" data-role="button">People</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="header" data-role="header" data-theme="b"> 
    <a id="bars-button" data-icon="bars" class="ui-btn-right" style="margin-top:10px;" href="#navpanel">Menu</a>


<!-- /About -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you supply code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: please refer to this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/2dN4M/

Comment: That's the link from the question that you referred to, but doesn't reproduce your actual issue.

Comment: this code is working fine, i want to add a scrollable functionality  to the menu, actually  i have a bit more element to the menu

Comment: create a div inside the panel, add css property `overflow-x: scroll` and for `.ui-panel-inner { overflow-x: hidden }`. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/CdNTq/

Comment: hey thanks for nice solution but i don't know where i am struggling.as i m totally new to jquery-mobile , still not working in my moblie device

Comment: Please refer the edited source code

Comment: you forgot this `$('.panel-content').css({
    'max-height': panelheight
})` it's in the fiddle. You can change _panelheight_ to any value. try 300px instead.

Comment: still not working , it is dragged with content.

Comment: what do you mean dragged with content?

Comment: this code is working well with high resolution mobile but getting problem with low resolution device. It is actually not scrolling individual with max-height:panelheight. but on 300px its scroll with full page

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37175/discussion-between-rachar-p-and-omar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now i am taking  above `overflow-x: scroll` and for `.ui-panel-inner { overflow-x: hidden }` as a solution ,as 
this is working fine with mostly devices except for few low resolution device 
please refer [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/CdNTq/)

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, jQuery Mobile's slide panel (FB like) it is not yet ready. I had some issues with fixed navbar and fixed footer. This why I started to search for a better alternative to solve this problem.

Here are some links that I found :

- http://www.berriart.com/sidr/#usage
- http://apptitudes.github.io/SlidingMenuJS/ (my favorite)
- http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/slide-and-push-menus/
- http://css-tricks.com/off-canvas-menu-with-css-target/

I know it doesn't solve your problem, but it might help in your futur development :)