# Jquery Reveal Panel With Fixed Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

In jquery panel http://api.jquerymobile.com/resources/panel/example1.html there are three types overlay,push,reveal.

But is there any way to reveal panel without moving the header ?Find my test code here in [this link](http://freegifts.in/auto/index.html)

Comment: Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027951/jquery-mobile-sliding-menu-under-header/17028477#17028477

Comment: my code works with _overlay_, i haven't tested it on _reveal_. However, I assume it's difficult to achieve it on _reveal_ and _push_.

Comment: Hi omar are you there ? can you come to chat ?

Comment: join same chat session of yesterday's.