# why header text hide when slide panel open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have panel in top header. After click on image (left on header) it shows the panel. Actually My problem is that whenever my panel is open my header title is hide("Test")in my example.First I used
`data-display="push"` it hides my header title ("Test"). But when I tried `data-display="overlay"` it doesn't hide my header title text but hides my image ..:( why can't I show both things at the same time?

http://jsfiddle.net/7Cmb3/1/

```
$(function () {   
  $('#panelOpenImge').click(function(){
    $( "#mypanel" ).panel( "open" );
  })
})
```

Comment: Why did you remove your previous Stack Overflow account and created new?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added some css code

```
@media ( min-width: 200px) {

    /* wrap on wide viewports once open */

    .ui-panel-page-content-open.ui-panel-page-content-position-left {
        margin-right: 17em;
    }
    .ui-panel-page-content-open.ui-panel-page-content-position-right {
        margin-left: 17em;
    }
    .ui-panel-page-content-open {
        width: auto;
    }

    .ui-panel-page-content-open.ui-panel-page-content-position-left.ui-panel-page-content-display-push {
        margin-right: 17em;
    }
    .ui-panel-page-content-open.ui-panel-page-content-position-right.ui-panel-page-content-display-push {
        margin-left: 17em;
    }
    .ui-panel-page-content-open.ui-panel-page-content-display-push {
        width: auto;
    }

}
```

please check

http://jsfiddle.net/7Cmb3/7/

Comment: @mr.corococo correct answer so I need to add css for all screen

Comment: can you please exaplain one more thing it apply on all screen whose width is more than 200 ?

Comment: yes. the css will work on screen with width is more than 200px. however, you can change that value to whatever you need.

Comment: can we add and condition like 200 to 300 width like?

Answer (score 0):

I changed `data-display="overlay"` and applied the following code to calculate the height of the panel accordingly

```
$(function () {   
    $('#panelOpenImge').click(function(){
        $( "#mypanel" ).panel( "open"  );
    });
    var header = $('[data-role=header]').outerHeight();
    var panel = $('#mypanel').height();
    var panelheight = panel - header;
    $('.ui-panel').css({
        'top': header,
        'min-height': panelheight
    });
});
```

All credits to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17028477/1374307)

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7Cmb3/2/)

Comment: this is wrong answer ..i need like this http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/demos/panels/panel-nav-form.html

Comment: please remove your answer

Comment: Please remove your answer so that other will answer that question

Comment: You didn't add the code part I wrote to your fiddle. 
You should have checked my fiddle at least.
Anyways am glad you got an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Cmb3/5/)**

```
$(function () {   
    $('#panelOpenImge').click(function(){

        $( "#mypanel" ).panel( "open"  );

    });
    var panel = $('#mypanel').height();
    var panelheight = panel - header;
    $('.ui-panel').css({
       'min-height': panelheight
    });
});
```

Comment: as i said I need responsive http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/demos/panels/panel-nav-form.html

Comment: Working on jQuery mobile.Just a min.

Comment: First please check this demo

Comment: In this demo "+" remain display on screen when panel is open and panel is closed