# Jquery Mobile Panel Content Height?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am dynamically building list view inside panel using jquery mobile and mvc4.

1) Our 1st requirement is the panel should come below header. The below code works perfectly.

```
$(document).on("panelbeforeopen", function (event, ui) {
  var header = $('[data-role=header]').outerHeight();
  var panel = $('.ui-panel').height();
  var panelheight = panel - header;

  $('.ui-panel').css({
    'top': header,
    'min-height': panelheight
  });

});
```

2) The next requirement is the panel height should be depending upon number of li inside panel. example if i have 2 li in panel then the max-height should be equal to 2 li there should not be any empty face in bottom.

Please Guide Me

1) I tried below code

```
$(document).on("panelbeforeopen", function (event, ui) {

  var header = 50;
  var panel = $('.ui-panel').height();
  var panelheight = panel - header;
  var Uiinnes = $('.ui-panel-inner').height();

  $('.ui-panel').css({
    'top': header,
    'min-height': panelheight,
    'max-height' : Uiinnes
  });

});
```

Getting value in Uiinnes and i assigned to 'max-height' but no use.

Comment: if listview is shorter than _view port_, the panel will look ugly. If it's longer, it will cause page to scroll. Edit: I'm glad [_my code_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17028477/1771795) worked for you ;)

Comment: @Omar : yes dude. U saved me. But its client requirement. So no option.

Comment: then do the same, var listview = $(".listview", this).outerHeight(); $(this).css({"height": listview});`

Comment: @Omar : I tried but its not working. Then i tried below code.

 var header = 50;
       var panel = $('.ui-panel').height();
       var panelheight = panel - header;
       var Uiinnes = $('.ui-panel-inner').height();

       $('.ui-panel').css({
           'top': header,
           'min-height': panelheight,
           'max-height' : Uiinnes

I getting value in Uiinnes but no change in height. Still panel occupying full height of window.

Comment: @Omar Please see my updated post for clarity.

Comment: are you using overlay, push or reveal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55500/discussion-between-ryder-and-omar).

Answer (score 1):

I found this works pretty well.

```
//set panel to display below the header and height to listview height
var header = $('[data-role=header]').outerHeight();
var panel = $('.ui-panel').height();
var panelheight = panel - header;
var lVHeight = $('#panelListView').height();

$('.ui-panel').css({
    'top': header,
    'min-height': lVHeight-21,
    'max-height' : lVHeight-21
});
```

Not sure why $('#panelListView').height(); comes back longer than actual list view, but subtracted 21 and works fine. Probably has bottom margin.

BGecko

Comment: A popup with a listview performs very similar. I actually changed my code to use it instead.